# Is it ok to mount a folder into root of docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, webserver

I have a docker webserver and I'm mounting my `./uploads/` folder  into `/uploads/` but to get it to work I have to do

```
location ~ /uploads/ {
    root /;
}
```

Nginx says not to use `root /;`, but I'm, not sure if I'm ok doing this because its actaully going to `/uploads/` [Nginx wiki](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#not-using-standard-document-root-locations)

Is this ok or what can I do for this to be correct & secure

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says, map your './uploads' to '/usr/share/www/uploads' and then you won't have any issues. And replace /uploads/ with the new location and remove the "root /" declaration that should definitely not be there.